# Creating a hash using a function

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am trying to create a hash using a function in perl. Actually i was working on creating a binary search tree in perl. Below is the code :

```
sub newhash {
  $data = shift;
  $left = undef;
  $right = undef;
  %node = ("data"=>$data,"left"=>$left,"right"=>$right);
  return (\%node);
}

$firstele = newhash(2);
foreach ( keys %$firstele )
{
  print "$_:$firstele->{$_}\n";
}

$node = newhash(1);

foreach ( keys %$node )
{
  print "$_:$node->{$_} \n";
}

foreach ( keys %$firstele )
{
  print "$_:$firstele->{$_}\n";
}
```

The trouble is that when i am printing the original hash, the data key gets replaced by whatever i am passing to the `newhash` function . The output:

```
left:
right:
data:2
left:
right:
data:1
left:
right:
data:1
```

Any ideas why is the data key getting replaced?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Answer (score 6):

`use strict;` would tell you about a bunch of undeclared variables; lexicalize them with `my` and it should solve your problem.  As it stands, there's only one `%node` and you overwrite it with every call to `newhash`.

```
use strict;

sub newhash {
    my $data = shift;
    my $left;
    my $right;
    my %node = ( # <-- a brand new %node every time
        data  => $data,
        left  => $left,
        right => $right,
    );
    return (\%node); # new %node, new reference
}

my $firstele = newhash(2);
print "firstele data: $firstele->{data}\n";

my $node = newhash(1);
print "node     data: $node->{data}\n";    
print "firstele data: $firstele->{data}\n";
```

Comment: How to make the 2 lines code block of **foreach** loop into a single line? `foreach (keys %$head) {
    print "head->$_ = $head->{$_}\n" if $head->{$_};
    print "head->$_ = NULL\n" if ! $head->{$_};
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for adding elements in BT structure.

use strict;

use List::Util qw(first);

my (@input,$data);

print "Enter the data for being in a BST structure: ";

$data=<>;

chomp($data);

my $root=$data;

push(@input,$data);

while($data =~ m/\b-?\d{1,3}\b/){

```
my $idx=first { $input[$_] == $root } 0..$#input;

    if($data<$root) {

        for(my $i=0;$i<=$idx;$i++) {

            next if($data>$input[$i]) ;

            if($data<$input[$i]) {

                splice(@input,$i,0,$data);

            }

            last;

        }

    }

    if($data>$root) {

        for(my $i=$idx;$i<=$#input;$i++) {

            if($data>$input[$i]) {

                if(($i+1==scalar(@input)) or ($data<$input[$i+1] && $i+1 !=
```

scalar(@input))) {

```
                    splice(@input,$i+1,0,$data);

                    last;

                }

                else  {

                    next;

                }

            }               

            last;

        }

    }

print "Enter the number for being in a BT structure: ";

$data=<>;

chomp($data);
```

}

print "Final BT Array:\n",join(',', @input),"\n";